# Is there a way to prevent GLKView from clearing the context before calling drawRect:?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I would like to add content to my canvas without clearing and redrawing the content I've previously drawn. Is that possible? Right now I re-draw all the content every time `drawRect:` gets called and it time, that makes things sluggish.

EDIT:
`clearsContextBeforeDrawing` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL is very flexible.  I don't know what drawRect: method  is even though you don't have to call this method every time. Maybe NStimer or CADisplayLink call the drawRect method and also call GLClear () in drawRect.
So you can change this in any form.

Comment: Probably neither of them call `drawRect` but I think it's synchronised with `CADisplayLink`. In any case, it seems I have only my lack of experience to blame, since it seems **I** was the one calling `glClear` earlier in some obscure place.